# How to use Git for pulling remote branch

Tags: git

The git server I am trying to pull has a new branch . (call it branch-9)

In my local, I don't have that and I do I pull it to my local computer?

should I run this?

```
$git checkout -b branch-9
$git pull branch-9
```

is that the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a `git fetch` will, if you have configured the git server as a remote, create a local tracking branch.

```
git fetch
git checkout branch-9 # This will automatically set up to track "origin/branch-9"
```

The long form of the above command is:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b branch-9 origin/branch-9
```

*after* you've started making local changes to your copy of `branch-9`, then you might want to use `git pull`. `git pull` is the same as `git fetch` and either `git merge` or `git rebase` (depending on your settings, defaulting to `git merge`).

Answer (score 1):

First get a local copy of the remote branch:

```
git fetch
```

This will create `origin/branch-9`. Now check-out a `branch-9`:

```
git checkout branch-9
```

This will create a new local branch that tracks the remote branch.

Comment: so, let's say currently i m check out in master..
So, i stay in master, and then "git fetch", and then "git checkout branch-9", right?